# Plugin to automatically change anchor text of urls to the destinations title?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, seo

Say I link to http://www.glumbo.com on one of my posts. I want wordpress to automatically change the anchor text of the link to glumbo.com's title. How can I do this?

Comment: Two issues with this - you will need to cache a lot of those titles and it will look spammy (page titles for anchors is common technique in spam). Are you sure you want to titles for anchors? Why not site's domain or something?

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm only asking this because vbSEO does this for vBulletin installations and I see it being used on many websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decided to entertain the idea. Adapted from my snippet that [changes anchors to collapsed domain names](http://themehybrid.com/support/topic/reformatting-commenters-urls). Little too verbose, but seems to work.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'anchors_to_page_titles' );

function anchors_to_page_titles( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', $content, $matches );
    array_shift( $matches );

    foreach( $matches[0] as $key => $url ) {

    $anchor = $matches[1][$key];

    if( $url == $anchor ) {

        $transient_key = 'page_title_'.md5($url);
        $anchor = get_transient($transient_key);

        if( !$anchor ) {

            $response = wp_remote_request($url);
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
            $pattern = '/title>(.*?)</';
            $title = array();
            preg_match( $pattern, $body, $title);

            if( !empty( $title ) ) {

                $title = $title[1];
                $anchor = $title;
                set_transient( $transient_key, $anchor, 60*60*24 );
            }
            else {
                $anchor = $url;
                set_transient( $transient_key, $anchor, 60*60 );
            }
        }

        $content = str_replace( ">{$url}</a>", ">{$anchor}</a>", $content );
    }

    }

    return $content;
}
```

PS maybe it would make sense to modify post on save rather than filtering on display... Well, as per my comment I don't think page titles are good for this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great page that give numerous downloadable examples of how to change the text inside an anchor using  jQuery.  They are really helpful for web 2.0 and web 3.0 sites.

http://www.ajaxera.com/jquery-change-text-in-anchor/